# How can I make a grid wrap around its content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am working on this layout. Whenever the user clicks on the left side button, related information is displayed on the right side as shown in image.

[image]

I am using grid properties and JavaScript function to toggle left and right content but getting this result.

[image]

Whenever I click on the button **fix consultation**, it shows the right side grid but pushes all the buttons down to occupy second grid height.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
function div1() {
  let x = document.getElementById("div1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.innerWrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innerWrapper">
    <div class="button1">
      <button type="button" placeholder="01 Fix consultation" class="section_button" onclick="div1()">
                <label class="section_button_label">
                    <span class="id_no">01</span> Fix consultation
                </label>
            </button>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" style="display: block;">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img1.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Fix consultation</header>
      <p>
        This dipicts that user will have to fix appointment first when it select perticular doctor
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What I would do

I recommend not to use grid layout here. Grid layout is **intendet** to do what you do not want to have: That the rows have the same height.

I recommend to use two divs, one for the left and one for the right side. The right side displays the buttons, the left shows the images with their description. I added a snippet below that shows what I mean.

Also note that there are quite a few improvements for your code:

1. Do not use the `label` tag in your `button`. `label` tags are for `input` and `select`. I'm not sure if this is a syntactical error but it just doesn't look right.
2. Do not use `onclick` but use [Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. This way the javascript code is separated from your markup, you can remove the listener again and you can add multiple listeners, not just one.
3. Do not use inline `style` attribute if possible. Always use CSS. I also prefere to toggle CSS classes for visibility instead of setting the `style` directly. But this is personal taste I guess.
4. Do not mix classes and ids. If you have a class that is `button03` this class only exists once. So it should be an `id`. To select an element by its `id` is a lot simpler (in javascript) than selecting it by its class. Also it just is not the purpose to have classes that are unique for one element.

```js
(function(){
  const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("section_button");
  
  if(buttons !== null){
    for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
      buttons.item(i).addEventListener("click", function(){
        const div_id = this.getAttribute("data-image-id");

        // remove the following line and the complete following if to keep all
        // images visible
        const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image-wrapper > div.shown:not(#" + div_id + ")");
        if(images !== null){
          for(let j = 0; j < images.length; j++){
            images.item(j).classList.remove("shown");
          }
        }
        
        if(typeof div_id == "string"){
          const img = document.getElementById(div_id);
          img.classList.add("shown");
        }
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.button-wrapper{
  margin-right: 10px;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.section_button{
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.section_button:hover{
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 13px;
}

.image-wrapper{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.image-wrapper > div:not(.shown){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" placeholder="01 Fix consultation" class="section_button" data-image-id="div1">
        <span class="id_no">01</span> Fix consultation
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" placeholder="02 Bla bla bla" class="section_button" data-image-id="div2">
        <span class="id_no">02</span> Bla bla bla
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" placeholder="03 Bla bla bla" class="section_button" data-image-id="div3">
        <span class="id_no">03</span> Bla bla bla
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" placeholder="04 Bla bla bla" class="section_button" data-image-id="div4">
        <span class="id_no">04</span> Bla bla bla
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img1.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Fix consultation</header>
      <p>
        This dipicts that user will have to fix appointment first when it select perticular doctor
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img2.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Bla bla bla 2</header>
      <p>
        Bla bla bla 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Bla bla bla 3</header>
      <p>
        Bla bla bla 3
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div4">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Bla bla bla 4</header>
      <p>
        Bla bla bla 4
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Your solution

If you still want to stick with your grid layout for any reason, you can use the [`grid-row` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) to set a bigger rowspan. This means that the image will span over all the following rows. Note that you should hide the other images then, otherwise they will overlap.

The following snippet shows this solution.

A second idea to use would be to wrap the image div (e.g. `div1`) by another div. Make the image div (e.g. `div1`) absolute (`position: absolute`) and make the new surrounding div relative (`position: relative`). This way the image does not dictate the size of the row.

```js
function div1() {
  let x = document.getElementById("div1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function div2() {
  let x = document.getElementById("div2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function div3() {
  let x = document.getElementById("div3");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function div4() {
  let x = document.getElementById("div4");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.innerWrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

div[class^="button"]{
  grid-column: 1;
}

#div1{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1/5;
}

#div2{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2/5;
}

#div3{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

#div4{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innerWrapper">
    <div class="button1">
      <button type="button" placeholder="01 Fix consultation" class="section_button" onclick="div1()">
        <label class="section_button_label">
            <span class="id_no">01</span> Fix consultation
        </label>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" style="display: block;">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img1.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Fix consultation</header>
      <p>
        This dipicts that user will have to fix appointment first when it select perticular doctor
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button2">
      <button type="button" placeholder="02 bla bla bla" class="section_button" onclick="div2()">
        <label class="section_button_label">
            <span class="id_no">02</span> Bla bla bla
        </label>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="display: none;">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img1.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Fix consultation</header>
      <p>
        This dipicts that user will have to fix appointment first when it select perticular doctor
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button3">
      <button type="button" placeholder="03 bla bla bla" class="section_button" onclick="div3()">
        <label class="section_button_label">
            <span class="id_no">03</span> Bla bla bla
        </label>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" style="display: none;">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img1.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Fix consultation</header>
      <p>
        This dipicts that user will have to fix appointment first when it select perticular doctor
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button4">
      <button type="button" placeholder="04 bla bla bla" class="section_button" onclick="div4()">
        <label class="section_button_label">
            <span class="id_no">04</span> Bla bla bla
        </label>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="div4" style="display: none;">
      <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/appdev.konfinity.com/css/tasks/img1.png" height="300px" width="300px">
      <header>Fix consultation</header>
      <p>
        This dipicts that user will have to fix appointment first when it select perticular doctor
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and efforts. i will go through it and make necessary changes

Comment: You are welcome :) If this is the answer you were hoping for, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the tick below the votes on the top left. This way the system closes the question (it doesn't appear for others anymore). You will also [receive reputation for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: i tried to implement this into website but its not working. when i click on button it does not show image...